# How to get binary file from Broker DB using CIL?

Tags: web8.5, binary, cil

I am using SDL Web 8.5 and it has been configured to publish content and images to Broker DB.

I have a Restful web service (written in Java) which is using CIL to get Component Presentation as JSON. As part of the JSON output, I am getting the image path.

This JSON is consumed by some frontend application. But the image is just a path in JSON.

Could anyone guide me on how to send the image to the calling application?

Comment: why do you want to send image as binary at all? All you need is to let consumer of your service read the image from that location. I hope that your image location is relative path.

Comment: Yes @MarkoMilic, it is relative path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Shiva already answered might helpful for using .NET CIL.

To get the Binary using Java CIL.

**Java Example:**

```
import com.sdl.web.api.dynamic.BinaryContentRetrieverImpl;
import com.sdl.web.api.dynamic.DynamicMetaRetrieverImpl;
import com.tridion.data.BinaryData;
import com.tridion.dynamiccontent.DynamicMetaRetriever;
import com.tridion.meta.BinaryMeta;
import com.sdl.web.api.content.BinaryContentRetriever;
import com.google.common.io.Files;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SDLCILTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DynamicMetaRetriever dynamicMetaRetriever = new DynamicMetaRetriever();
        String urlPath = "/media/map_tcm5-316.jpg";
        String path = "c://temp/test.jpg";

        final File file = new File(path);
        BinaryMeta binaryMeta = dynamicMetaRetriever.getBinaryMetaByURL(urlPath);
        int itemId = (int) binaryMeta.getURI().getItemId();
        int publicationId = 5;

        //WebComponentMetaFactory factory = new WebComponentMetaFactoryImpl(publicationId);
        //ComponentMeta componentMeta = factory.getMeta(itemId);
        //long componentTime = componentMeta.getLastPublicationDate().getTime();

        //TODO based on component metadata date modified - fetch only if file is modified

        BinaryContentRetriever binaryContentRetriever = new BinaryContentRetrieverImpl();
        BinaryData binaryData = binaryContentRetriever.getBinary(publicationId, itemId, binaryMeta.getVariantId());

        try {
            Files.write(binaryData.getBytes(), file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Exception("Cannot write new loaded content to a file " + file, e);
        }
    }
}
```

For some DXA references for CIL to download Binary could be useful for you.

[CilStaticContentResolver.java](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/blob/f341566cf51e1d3519f3c01b7d6e98dc21d076f6/dxa-framework/dxa-tridion-common/src/main/java/com/sdl/dxa/tridion/content/CilStaticContentResolver.java)

[GenericStaticContentResolver.java](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/blob/f341566cf51e1d3519f3c01b7d6e98dc21d076f6/dxa-framework/dxa-tridion-common/src/main/java/com/sdl/dxa/tridion/content/GenericStaticContentResolver.java)

For Microservices URLs for your reference how that CIL API's get converted to get the Binaries, you can play around with the postman.

```
http://localhost:8081/client/v4/content.svc/GetDynamicMetaFunctionImport(Url='%252Fmedia%252Fmap_tcm5-316.jpg',ItemType='BinaryMeta')

http://localhost:8081/client/v2/content.svc/BinaryContents(PublicationId=5,BinaryId=316,VariantId=WyNkZWYjXQ==,StreamContent=false)

http://localhost:8081/client/v2/content.svc/BinaryContents(BinaryId=316,PublicationId=5,VariantId='ZGVmYXVsdA==')/$value
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Velmurugan, but getBinaryMetaByURL(urlPath) is returning Null. Also, if I used binaryContentRetriever.getBinary("tcm:5-316"), I am getting the BinaryData.

Answer (score 4):

Binary should be treated as a separate entity similar to pages and component presentations. In your case, you would need your Rest service to serve your binary as a stream.

Like Mark highlighted, you would only need the relative path in the JSON to avoid further manipulation.

A DD4T relevant example can be found at https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.RestService.WebApi. You can retrieve a page by using `http://myservice/page/getcontentbyurl/{publicationId}/{extension}/{url}` and a binary with something like `http://myservice/binary/GetBinaryByUri/{publicationId:int}/{id:int}`

Comment: Thanks @Shiva. Will send the response as a Stream or byte[]